# Sum-of-products, simplication

Tags: boolean-algebra

can you help to simply the following boolean expression?

**F = /ABC + /AB/C + ABC + AB/C + /A/BC + /A/B/C**

Using an online I found out the solution which should be

**= B + /A**

But I am not sure of the last step

= /AB(C + /C) + AB(C + /C)  +  /A/B( C + /C ) simplify using rule 6

= /AB + AB + /A/B    (OR Distributive Law)

= B(/A + A) + /A/B  simplify using rule 6

= B + /A/B      expand using Distributive law

until here (**B + /A/B**) I think I am correct

From here below I am not sure I took the right way

**= (B + /B)(B +/A)     AND Distributive law A + (B.C) = (A + B).(A + C)**

**= (B + /B)(B +/A) simplify using rule 6**

= B + /A

Comment: It's the "OR Absorption Law". Look for a proof of it (well, can be easily proven using truth table, but you can find algebraic way as well)

Comment: With your notation of `/`, I cannot determine if they are broken overbars or a single overbar. Consider using Mathjax notation... Example: `\$\overline{A}\$` = \$\overline{A}\$

Comment: hi @KingDuken  the "/" stands for NOT gate

Comment: Thanks for trying to clarify. However, I was mentioning how `/` could be ambiguous as "/A/B" could mean \$\overline{AB}\$ or \$\overline{A} \, \, \overline{B}\$, which are two different equations

Comment: thanks @KingDuken for  your comment, for \$\overline{AB}\$ I would rather use /(AB)

Comment: Hmmm it's a pity written logic functions are not more standardised.  I've seen ~ and a few other things for not before, but foreslash is new to me.

Comment: @KH yes that drives me crazy as well, we can use /A,A',~A,\$\overline{A}\$ :D

Comment: @KH It comes from "back in the day" when all we had was "ASCII" (or worse -- boudot or [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) code.) We didn't have ***any*** fancy-pants graphics displays. So we used "/" to indicate "NOT." (Or "~" sometimes with the advent of full ASCII support when that came along.) Of course, things change over time. Did you know that I used to post schematics written in pure ASCII characters that were perfectly readable? I even wrote a program to take LTspice schematic captures and generate ASCII schematics from it, automatically. Still works, too.

Comment: For simple boolean logic problems (up to 4 inputs) I would draw a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).  Remember to plot a truth table of your original function and the proposed simplification to check they are identical.

Comment: thanks @WarrenHill for . your comment, the question required explicitly to use the Algebra Boolean rules

Comment: If you are specifically asked to use boolean algebra for this it should be in the question.  Also what is rule 6? Either state it explicitly or provide a link.  The rules are well known but not by numbers.  I've extended my answer to include this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceeding from your second step above,

= /AB + AB + /A/B  (OR Distributive Law)

= /AB + /AB + AB + /A/B

= /AB + AB + /A/B + /AB

= B(/A + A) + /A(/B + B)

= B + /A

Comment: How did you step 
from = /AB + AB + /A/B (OR Distributive Law) 
to = /AB + "/AB" + AB + /A/B ?
How the second "/AB" show up?

Comment: The OR operation has the property of Idempotence: X = X + X

Answer (score 3):

**F = /ABC + /AB/C + ABC + AB/C + /A/BC + /A/B/C**

\$ F =  \bar{A}BC +\bar{A}B\bar{C}+ABC+AB\bar{C}+\bar{A}\bar{B}C+\bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C} \$

We can plot this as a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
  \text{}&\bar{B}&B&B&\bar{B}\\
  \hline
  \bar{A}&1&1&1&1 \\
  A&0&1&1&0 \\
  \hline
  \text{}&\bar{C}&\bar{C}&C&C
\end{array}
$$

Which by inspection we can see simplifies to \$B+\bar{A}\$

For completeness you should plot the truth table for both to confirm they are identical.

---

For an algebraic approach using [DeMorgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

We can start by rearranging to collect all the \$ \bar{A} \$  terms.

\$ F = \bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C}+\bar{A}\bar{B}C+\bar{A}B\bar{C}+\bar{A}BC+AB\bar{C} +ABC\$

Giving

\$F =\bar{A}\cdot(\bar{B}\bar{C}+\bar{B}C+B\bar{C}+BC)+AB\bar{C}+ABC \$

Now collecting on \$ \bar{B}\$ and \$ B \$

\$ F=\bar{A}\cdot(\bar{B}\cdot(\bar{C}+C)+B\cdot(\bar{C}+C))+AB\cdot{(\bar{C}+C)}\$

Now since \$ \bar{C} +C =1 \$ we can simplify further.

\$ F=\bar{A}\cdot(\bar{B}+B) +AB\$

and since \$ \bar{B} +B =1 \$ we get.

\$ F = \bar{A}+AB \$

Since \$ \bar{A} \$ does not care about \$B\$ we can see that we could add \$ \bar{A}B \$ without changing the result

since \$ \bar{A} = \bar{A}\cdot(\bar{B}+B) = \bar{A} \bar{B} + \bar{A}B \$ = \$ \bar{A} + \bar{A}\bar{B} = \bar{A} + \bar{A}B \$

due to the property of idempotence

Giving.
`
\$F = \bar{A} +\bar{A}B+AB = \bar{A}+B\cdot(\bar{A}+A)=\bar{A}+B\$

Comment: hanks @WarrenHill for your answer, 
but the question requires explicitly to use the Algebra Boolean laws and rule,
Karnaugh map are not allowed

Comment: when you add \$\overline{A}\$B you mean to use the property of Idempotence: X = X + X ?

Comment: Yes, Updated to make idempotence explicit.

Answer (score 3):

The simplification is not particularly difficult.

\begin{align} F &= \bar{A}BC + \bar{A}B\bar{C} + ABC + AB\bar{C} + \bar{A}\bar{B}C  + \bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C} \\
 &= A \left( \underbrace{BC + B\bar{C}}_{= B} \right) + \bar{A} \left(\underbrace{ \underbrace{BC + B\bar{C}}_{=B} + \underbrace{\bar{B}C + \bar{B}\bar{C}}_{= \bar{B}} }_{= 1}\right) \\
 &= AB + \bar{A} \\
 &= B + \bar{A}
\end{align}

The only difficulty lies in the step to the last line. There you may use a simple substitution:
$$\bar{A} = \bar{A} + \bar{A}B $$

Left-hand and right-hand side are equal! (If you don't see it, use the already mentioned Karnaugh diagram.)

Comment: +1 for the impressive mathjax skills...

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I don't know anything about MathJax. I wrote normal LaTeX, except that I had to google to get the aligment correct.

Comment: For reference there is a [Mathjax tutorial here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  It is very similar to LaTeX in many respects.